# Pass additional context data apart from the message in wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client, wcf-endpoint

All,

We have a message inspector that logs the incoming and outgoing soap messages to a custom db, going forward we need to corelate the request and response based on a guid/some id which is **NOT** present in  the request nor the response message.

Is there a way we can pass additional information to the message inspector say few context properties apart from the messqge

Answer (score 0):

Message inspector has correlationState which you can use to correlate Recieve/Send. Return the correlation token from AfterRecieveRequest if in services and consume it in BeforeSendReply. On the client its AfterReceiveReply you return correlation token.

```
public interface IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext);
    void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState);
}

public interface IClientMessageInspector
{
    void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState);
    object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel);
}
```